# C++ bouncing ball goes out of screen

Tags: c++, bgi

I tried making a simple bouncing ball with constant velocity, that is supposed to bounce of the screen edges.
I have succeeded in making the ball move forward and down, but it does not stop and instead keeps moving and goes out of the screen.
Also, I just started c++ graphics yesterday and the program is quite primitive and thus I'd appreciate it if the answer could be simple.

(All Header files are included)

```
void main()
{ 
   int gdriver = DETECT, gmode, xmax, ymax, Vx=10, Vy=10, Cx=150, Cy=150, t=1;
   initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "");
   xmax = getmaxx();
   ymax = getmaxy();
   setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, YELLOW);
   a:
   while((Cx!=xmax-5 && Cx!=0) || (Cy!=ymax-5 && Cy!=0))
   { 
     Cx += (Vx * t);
     Cy += (Vy * t);
     clrscr();
     pieslice(Cx,Cy,0,360,10);
     delay(100);
   }
   if (Cx==xmax-5 || Cx==0)
   {
     Vx = - Vx;
   }
   else if (Cy==ymax-5 || Cy==0)
   {
     Vy = - Vy;
   }
   goto a;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest deleting the newlines between every pair of codeline. =)

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and provide a [mcve]. Welcome to SO.

Comment: `while(Cx!=xmax-5 || Cx!=0 || Cy!=ymax-5 || Cy!=0)` unless `ymax-5 == 0` and `xmax-5==0` this condition is always `true`

Comment: But how? There is an OR operator there and they are separate conditions.

Comment: example: `int x` is **always** either not 0 or not 5, you probably meant not 0 **and** not equals to `ymax-5` only then it breaks when it is 0 or `ymax-5`

Comment: see also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: You know about loops, and yet you felt an urge to write `goto`?

Comment: @user463035818: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Comment: Okay, I changed the operator to AND but it's still not working. The ball just falls out of the screen.

Comment: goto?? did I saw a goto?? Are you a time traveller?

Comment: Related:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: *Constant velocity*? `Cx += (Vx * t);` and `t++` at each step is not constant velocity to me, `Cx` doesn't evolves linearly...

Comment: Is it really that big of a problem that I use goto?

Comment: @Drag040: No, but lots of people pretend that it is.

Comment: @UKMonkey Thanks for the advice. Will keep it in mind from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(Cx!=xmax-5 || Cx!=0 || Cy!=ymax-5 || Cy!=0)
```

This is always true!

Whatever the value of `Cx`, it is *always* either "not `xmax-5`" or "not zero" (well, unless `xmax-5` itself is zero, which it is probably isn't).

Similarly, your `Cy` conditions always hold.

So, the ball always moves.

Instead:

```
while ((Cx!=xmax-5 && Cx!=0) || (Cy!=ymax-5 && Cy!=0))
```

Now you still have the problem that the horizontal and vertical movement is checked at once, which only works if the ball hits an exact corner. But I'll leave you to work that one out on your own.

Comment: okay, I understand the error in the condition and I made the necessary changes, but i don't really get what you mean by the horizontal and vertical movements being checked at once. I separated them into two different if-else statements so that they would be checked separately, but is that not good enough?

Comment: @Drag040: Step through your program's logic with pencil and paper to find out what it does given certain inputs.

Comment: Got it. I put a specific value against which the movements were checked  for equality when they would never be equal to that value because of the inputs I gave it.